# dynamically display posts of a user-chosen category without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a blog posts page that looks similar to this:
https://magnolia.com/blog/

What I want to do is when the user clicks on a category, only posts of that type display below the search. The above page accomplishes that by updating the whole page, but I want the posts to change their display to none so the page doesn't have to get reloaded every time and so the featured post stays on the page.  I have a list of links that display the tags for the posts, with their IDs being the possible post tag IDs.

```
<div class="page-links" >
        <ul class="link-list">
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#0" id="0">All</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#467" id="467">Joy</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#888" id="888">Forgiveness</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#830" id="830">Family</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#1014" id="1014">Faith</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#1018" id="1018">Temples</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#950" id="950">Agency</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#430" id="430">Grace</a></li>
          <li class="link-list-item"><a href="#1288" id="1288">Revelation</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

The posts are displayed using this code ($class_list being a list of all the tag IDs associated with that post)

```
<div class="post-block <?php echo $class_list; ?>">
    <div class="post-title">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($article->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($article->ID); ?></a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content article-sub" style="position: relative;">
        <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $num_words, $more_text);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what I want is when a user clicks on "Joy", all of the posts with the class "467" are displayed, but all of the posts that do not have that class are hidden with display: none.  And if "All" is clicked, all posts are displayed.  I know I have to use a hook in my .js file, but I am not very familiar with it and could use any help I can get.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to use a javascript framework and leverage a for-each of some sort. Barring that, here's a native js way:

First off, you can't have an html id attribute start with a number. Let's assume you've prefixed all your ids with "tag_".

**Javascript** (uses ES6 - make note if you're supporting old browsers)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var listElement         = document.querySelector(".link-list")
    var postBlockElements   = document.querySelectorAll(".post-block")

    listElement.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if(e.target.tagName !== "A") return;

        let id = e.target.id  

        postBlockElements.forEach(el => {
            el.style.display = el.classList.contains(id) || id === "tag_0"
                ? "block"
                : "none"
        })
    })      
</script>
```

This is a way, anyway (hopefully). I'm assuming a CMS isn't always flexible so we're working with what you've provided.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  `.post-block` does not contain all the posts, it is just for one post. Do I need to have a wrapper for all the posts? If not, how would that change the above code?  Also, does the javascript you gave me need to be in my .php file for that page or can I put it in my main .js file? And if I do that, how would I call the function?  And this is within WordPress if that helps.

Comment: @KristiPerkins I've refactored. The javascript could exist in the php file or in main.js, assuming your php file has a `<script src="main.js">` in it (or something to that effect).

Comment: (btw yes, there are no longer any html or css changes) .. as far as how to summon this in wordpress, I don't know wordpress. this code isn't in a function. if it's put into a .js file it will just run. you could put it in a function and run the function. up to you. sorry, the task is a bit broad to account for everything.

Comment: hopefully the smaller amount of code will be more easily digestible :)

Comment: It worked!  Thank you! Thank you! I did have to add a `)` to close off the `postBlockElements.forEach` function and put it after my php code or it didn't recognize the `.list-link` or `.post-block` elements.  But it works great now.

Comment: woohoo! yep you're right I made a typo! (fixing now)